# Java 8 streams: java.lang.IllegalStateException: End size 84758 is less than fixed size 84764

Tags: java, java-stream

I am using `Java 8 streams` API to transform values of map to array. I am getting following exception:

```
Unhandled exception ScheduledExecutorService : java.lang.IllegalStateException: End size 84758 is less than fixed size 84764
        at java.util.stream.Nodes$FixedNodeBuilder.end(Nodes.java:1232)
        at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:482)
        at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:471)
        at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:545)
        at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluateToArrayNode(AbstractPipeline.java:260)
        at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.toArray(ReferencePipeline.java:438)
        at com.turnoutnow.businesslogic.Worker.generateVisitsToESAndS3(Worker.java:213)
```

I am searching the exception on Google, but not finding anything useful around the error. Could anyone please tell me exactly what could be the reason for this error?

**EDIT**

Here is the single line of code where its coming:

```
visits.getVisitDataMap().values().stream().toArray(n -> new VisitDataBE[n]);
```

Comment: Please provide a minimal code example that reproduces the issue.

Comment: Actually, its coming in some internal project. And its pretty complex. Let me try.

Comment: You probably have a call to `toArray(IntFunction<A[]> generator)` somewhere. My guess is that the generator is creating an array of the wrong size.

Comment: @marstran, added the source of exception

Comment: I would just use a normal list instead of an array: `.collect(Collectors.toList())`. Pretty much no reason to use an array unless you're using some old API that doesn't accept lists.

Answer (score 3):

Your current code is correct as you are creating the array of the right size. You can simplify it to `.toArray(VisitDataBE[]::new)`.

Most likely other thread is removing elements from `visits.getVisitDataMap()` map while the `toArray()` is running. You can test this hypothesis by creating a defensive copy of the `Map`:

```
Map<...> copy = new HashMap<>(visits.getVisitDataMap());
copy.values().stream().toArray(n -> new VisitDataBE[n]);
```

The proper fix would depend on your application multi-threaded semantics.