# End size %d is less than fixed size %d

Tags: java

I use Java8 steam and CompletableFuture request method to get the return value,
What caused this exception?
I cannot reproduce this exception at the moment:

exception stack

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException

at java.util.stream.Nodes$FixedNodeBuilder.end(Nodes.java:1232)

at java.util.stream.Sink$ChainedReference.end(Sink.java:258)

at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:483)

at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:472)

at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:546)

at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluateToArrayNode(AbstractPipeline.java:260)

at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.toArray(ReferencePipeline.java:438)

//This line is my code
at com.xxx.XxxxServiceImpl.getDetail(XxxxServiceImpl.java:222)
```

End size 1 is less than fixed size 2

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
    ExecutorService executors = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);
    List<Integer> list = Lists.newArrayList(1, 2);
    Map<Integer, Long> map = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
    CompletableFuture.allOf(list.stream().map(obj -> CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(
            () -> getValue(), executors)
            .whenComplete((value, ex) -> {
                 
                if (ex != null) {
                    throw new BusinessException("exception" + ex);
                } else {
                    map.put(obj, value);
                }
            })).toArray(CompletableFuture[]::new)).join();
}

static Long getValue(){
    return System.currentTimeMillis();
}
```

Similar problem, but I did not modify this map and remove list
[Java 8 streams: java.lang.IllegalStateException: End size 84758 is less than fixed size 84764](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57274369/java-8-streams-java-lang-illegalstateexception-end-size-84758-is-less-than-fix)

Comment: What exception? Please post the full error message including its stack trace.

Comment: _"I did not modify this map"_ - and what is this `map.put(obj, value);`? You are modifying it.

Comment: I tried converting your code into something that would run.  Instead of an exception, I got a deadlock of some kind.  Could you please write a minimal reproducible example that we can compile and run to see the behavior that you are asking about.

Comment: @StephenC I can't reproduce the problem,
If my map type is HashMap, will it cause this exception?

Comment: @StephenC It may not be a deadlock but the lack of an `Executors.shutdown()` call.

Comment: @bytemamba - If you can't reproduce the problem ... there is nothing for us to answer.  You are (in effect) asking about the behavior of **different code**.  *"If my map type is `HashMap`, will it cause this exception?"* -  I have no idea.  Try it.  Does it?

Comment: If you want our help, you need to show us a minimal reproducible example that **does** exhibit the behavior you are talking about.

Comment: @取一个好的名字 were you able to solve the problem? I am also facing the same issue with `toList()` method

Answer (score 0):

> Similar problem, but I did not modify this map and remove list Java 8 streams: java.lang.IllegalStateException: End size 84758 is less than fixed size 84764

OK, so here's how you approach this problem ...

In order to get some stability into your code you need to isolate this complicated piece of logic and cover it by tests. This will make it easier to isolate and reproduce the problem.

The reason why you are get this error is because some elements in the stream can throw an exception and the size of the output is smaller than the size of the input.

Try removing the exception code for now and see if it works.
If it does not post the results in the comments.

Comment: delete exception, Still did not reproduce this exception

Answer (score 0):

I encountered a similar problem as well. I discovered that I was using `HashSet` in conjunction with `parallelStream()`. As `HashSet` is not thread-safe, I replaced it with `ConcurrentHashMap.newKeySet()`, which resolved the problem.